# Prove that $\forall x\in E, \exists z\in F\subset E,\; \inf_{y\in F}\|x-y\|=\|x-z\|$, where $F$ is compact and $E$ is a normed vector space.

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

> Let $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space and let $F\subseteq E$ be a non-empty compact subset. We define the *distance* from $x$ to $F$ as
> $$\begin{align}
> d\colon &E\times\mathcal{P}(E)\setminus \emptyset\to\mathbb{R}\\
> &(x,F)\mapsto\inf_{y\in F}\|x-y\|.
> \end{align}$$
> Prove that
> $$\forall x\in E,\exists z\in F,\; d(x,F)=\|x-z\|.$$

Definition of **compact set**: A set $F$ is said to be compact if and only if every sequence of elements of $F$ has a subsequence converging on $F$.

From this, it follow that $d(x,F)=0\iff x\in F$ (this was a previous problem and it only relies on $F$ being closed).
I don't really know where to start with the proof, any good hints (or incomplete work) would be great.

Comment: This follows from the continuity of the map $u\mapsto\|x-u\|$ and by compactness. Any real value function defined on a compact set $K$ attains it maxima and minima in $K$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{\|x- y\|: y \in F\}$ is bounded below, so the infimum exists. Let $z \in  E$ be such that $d(x,F)=\|x-z\|$. There exists a sequence $(y_n)$  in $F$ such that $(\|x-y_n\|)$ converges to $d(x,F)$. Then $|~\|x-y_n\|-\|x-z\|~|\rightarrow 0$. Now $\|x-y_n\| \leq \|x-z\|+\|y_n-z\|\Rightarrow -\|y_n-z\| \leq \|x-z\|-\|x-y_n\|$. Similarly $-\|y_n-z\| \leq \|x-y_n\|-\|x-z\|$. Thus $-\|y_n-z\| \leq |~\|x-y_n\|-\|x-z\|~|$. This implies $(y_n)$ converges to $z$. Since $F$ is closed $z \in F$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in E$ be fixed, and $F$ be compact. Then $f:E \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(y)=\|x-y\|$ is continuous, as the norm and the vector operations are continuous on $E$.

So $f[F]$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R$ and as such is closed and bounded and so has a minimum $m \in f[F]$, which means that there is $z \in F$ such that $m=f(z) \le f(y)$ for all $y \in F$. This implies that $d(x,F) = m = \|x - z\|$, as required.